# What does 垃海 mean in Shanghainese?

Tags: translation, phrase-meaning, shanghainese

I found this sentence on Tatoeba:

> 我会得垃海九点钟回来.
>   I will be back by nine.

What does ‘垃海’ mean in this sentence? My guess is ‘by [nine]’, but the phrase doesn’t show up on Wiktionary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the entry for 辣海 in《[上海方言词典](http://www.shanghainese.info/download/wugniu/%C9%CF%BA%A3%B7%BD%D1%D4%D4~%B5%E4.pdf)》on p. 311:

> [image]
>   [image]

The extracted text:

> 〖辣海〗la?˩˧꜖ he˥꜖꜔ =〖辣辣〗la?˩˧꜖
>   la˩˧꜖꜔（或la˩˧꜖꜔）❶表示人或事物的位
>   置：小王辣～？ ❷後接表示活動的
>   動詞，表示動作、事件正在進行之中：
>   大家儕～休息，儂吵 | 伊～想心事
>   ❸前接動詞、形容詞或動詞短語，表示
>   狀態的持續與北京話不同的是，“辣
>   海"和“辣辣"可前接動結式短語，後面
>   可加相當於“了"的語氣詞或“仔"：花
>   蠻紅～ | 我物事多～崍 | 坐～，能立
>   ～嗅 | 肉切好～睞，儂來燒好勒 ❹介
>   詞，表示時間、地點、範圍等，多置於謂
>   語動詞之前，但現在也有置於謂語動
>   詞之後的：～上海工作1坐一臺子高頭
>   卩“辣海"目前使用很普遍“海"有人
>   説成[ke]“辣海"説成[le ke]

---

There is also this paper [上海话"辣海"的语源及虚化特征的比较研究](https://xueshu.baidu.com/usercenter/paper/show?paperid=2293f57890242bc38842320f5ee30a8d&site=xueshu_se), in which the abstract says:

> [image]

The extracted text:

> "辣海"是上海话中一个重要的体标记词,本文通过跟邻近的江淮泰如片方言之间的比较研究,考察其来源及作为体标记的虚化过程."辣海"的"辣"本字不是"在",也不是"来",而是南方汉语方言的一个自源词;"海"的本字为"许",存在着不同的读音层次,"辣海"作为体标记在吴语中分别表示动作的进行和状态的持续,在泰如片方言主要表示状态的持续."在下"是"辣海"在泰如方言进一步虚化的产物,具有半虚化的体标记特征.

---

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shanghainese#Tones) also has this entry on their section for Shanghainese tones:

> to exist, here, present    [lɐʔ.hɛ]    徕許, 勒許

Comment: But what about 垃海? Doesn’t 辣海 mean something else?

Comment: @CookieDough It looks like their are multiple spellings for this word. The original spelling should be 来许 from what I can gather.

Comment: 来(come) 许 (about) + time = "by  + time" make sense

Comment: @Tang Ho Would I use 垃海 or 来许? Tatoeba doesn’t bring up anything when I try the latter - does this mean it isn’t used anymore?

Comment: I am not 上海人, so I wouldn't know which is the more common way to write this term

Comment: @CookieDough I would recommend using "辣海"; it doesn't really matter what the etymologically correct spelling is if you can't be understood.

Comment: @CookieDough I've added info from Wikipedia where they write it 徕許, 勒許.

Comment: There are similar cases in Cantonese, For example: 等/dang2/ is pronounced as  /ting3 / colloquially. Which  is exactly the same as  聽 when it is in colloquial form. Some people would write 等坐監 (wait to be put in prison) as 聽坐監  and not many people would object

Comment: The reason may be:  聽 (hear) also has the meaning of "to anticipate" as in 聽胡 ( one more match to win a game in Mahjong)

Comment: @Tang Ho 徕許 and 勒許 don’t seem to show up on Wiktionary, so I don’t know how accurate that is.

Comment: May be 徕許 or 勒許 had been replaced by 垃海 for too long,  and they became archaic

Comment: @CookieDough Not sure why you're asking Tang Ho, he's not the one who answered the question. Wiktionary is a very limited resource and it is missing a lot of entries.

Comment: @user3306356 please recommend me another resource to use. I'm aware that Wiktionary isn't the best resource to use, but there aren't that many resources for English speakers (besides wu-chinese.com) and my Mandarin isn't that good.

Answer (score 1):

> 我会得垃海九点钟回来

The mandarin equivalent is 我会在九点钟回来.  So, 垃海 means 在 here.  垃海 is not pronounced as its Pinyin "la1 hai3". It's more like "le gai2" or "le gei2".

Not sure the correct writing of the word anyway. Maybe "了该" is closer?